# Cos Norm of combinations of vectors using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra, normalization

I have 2 batches of sequences of 13x13 grids of 5 embedding vectors of 100 numbers. I want some embedding vectors to be very close to each other and other very far away when using a norm. How can i compute the l2 norm or other norm over all possible combinations of 2 embedding vectors from each batch? In the code bellow I tried to implement cos norm, but it becomes inf after some time. The 'tr' variable represents the embedding vectors that should be close to each other.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
if True:
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[2,2,13,13,5,100])
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[2,2,13,13,5,1])

    a11 = tf.reshape(a, [2, -1, 100])
    a1 = tf.layers.Dense(100)(a11)

    def triple_loss(pr, tr, batch_size=2, alpha=0.1, cos_norm=False, number_norm=False):
        '''face2vec loss
        pr: [b,h,w,boxes,embed]
        tr: [b,h,w,boxes,1]            
        returns: []'''
        b,l,h,w,bo,_ = tr.get_shape().as_list()     
        em = pr.get_shape().as_list()[-1] 
        tr_r = tf.reshape(tr,[-1, l*h*w*bo, 1])
        tr_tiled = tf.tile(tr_r,[1, 1, l*h*w*bo])#
        pr_reshaped = tf.reshape(pr,[-1, l*h*w*bo, em])
        embed_prod = tf.matmul(pr_reshaped, pr_reshaped, transpose_b=True)

        if cos_norm:                
            tr_norm = tf.reduce_sum(tf.sqrt(tr_tiled*tr_tiled),-1)
            tr_norm_tiled = tf.tile(tf.reshape(tr_norm,[-1, l*h*w*bo, 1]),[1, 1, l*h*w*bo])
            scale = tf.matmul(tr_norm_tiled, tr_norm_tiled, transpose_b=True)
            embed_prod = embed_prod/(scale+0.000001)
        if number_norm:
            return tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_mean(embed_prod*tr_tiled,[-1,-2]) /tf.reduce_sum(tr_r,[-1,-2])\
             - tf.reduce_mean(embed_prod*(1.0 - tr_tiled),[-1,-2])/tf.reduce_sum((1.0 - tr_r),[-1,-2]))\
             +alpha
        loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.reduce_mean(embed_prod*tr_tiled,[-1,-2]) \
                - tf.reduce_mean(embed_prod*(1.0 - tr_tiled),[-1,-2]))+alpha
        return loss
    loss = triple_loss(a1, b, cos_norm=True)

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-3)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    sess= tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    aa = np.zeros((2,2,13,13,5,100))
    aa[...,:2,:2]=1
    aa[...,0,1:3,1:2]=1
    bb = np.zeros((2,2,13,13,5,1))
    bb[:,:,:3,:3,:2,0] = 1.0
    for i in range(10):
        l = sess.run([loss,train_op],{a:aa, b:bb})
        print(l[-2])
```

the output is:

```
-320486.0
-2.02932e+12
-1.27284e+19
-8.06542e+25
-inf
nan
nan
```

Just with linear product between embedding vectors the network converges!

Answer (score 0):

To compute (squared) l2 norms for each pair of vectors, stack them in a matrix and multiply it by its transpose.

The loss you compute can be negative. The optimizer is achieving its goal of minimizing the loss very well - it reaches negative infinity. You need to make sure your loss is bounded from below.

Comment: it will take a lot of space and time to compute the differences between all the vectors combinations, cosine similarity on the other hand can be computed with  linear product between vectors and divided by their norm product.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. It says "How can i compute the l2 norm ... ?" Is there anything more you are wondering about?